# Getting voting errors, even when logged in

Tags: bug, voting

Yesterday I got the following error when I tried to vote on a post:

> An error has occurred - please retry your request.

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFSUL.png) Didn't happen every time, but every once in ~5 times. Simply pressing the vote arrow again usually worked to resolve the issue.

Today, I got a new one. Whilst being logged in to meta, I said:

> You must be logged in to vote

[image]

I was clearly logged in, as you can see. Pressing the voting arrow repeatedly did not work this time. Is something up with the voting system these days?

- I am using Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) with Firefox 66.0.4

---

Unrelated nitpick: there's a full stop at the end of the first error, but not after the second error. Could it please be added there? Same happens for the ["you can't vote for your own post"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjXtR.png), that also misses a dot, as well as "This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on".

Comment: Maybe it's a regional problem, I don't see any troubles myself.

Comment: @Gimby I don't see how, from an American server point of view, Switzerland and the Netherlands would be different. Aren't there Europe servers?

Comment: What does the network traffic look like for the vote request?

Comment: @DavidG of course I now see neither error...

Comment: Glitch in the Matrix maybe.

Comment: How long has it been since you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Some answers are not to be voted on ...

Comment: *Clearly* OP doesn't have enough reputation to vote /s